# lsusb in cygwin environment not working

Tags: cygwin, usb

I have downloaded and installed Cygwin in Windows 8. I connected a USB device and was trying to access it in Cygwin environment.

On typing lsusb i am getting below error. It says lsusb command not found

-bash: lsubs: command not found

I googled and found out that we have to install usbutils if we want to use lsusb. I tried doing it by giving below command but later found out that there is no such package in cygwin package list.

apt-cyg install usbutils

Any idea how to check usb devices connected by giving lsusb in cygwin?

Comment: Based on the error message above, looks like there is a typo in the command. Did you type `lsusb` or `lsubs` ?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me (Thanks to Juan Carlos Muñoz for pointing me in the right direction)

1. Run your cygwin setup (eg setup-x86_64.exe) - this is the setup, with which you installed cygwin.
2. Continue to the package selection and search for usbutils and install the one in the System category [image: install lsusb]
3. Complete the setup.

Now you should be able to use lsusb.

Answer (score 1):

The way to install packages in cygwin is through its setup.exe. Run setup-x86.exe or setup-x86_64.exe depending on your system (32 or 64-bit), and it will show you a list of packages you can install or update. I don't see usbutils, though. I see only a libusb that I have not installed.

Good luck with your search.